# create a tunnel for file transfer using SCP

Tags: portforwarding, tunnel, libssh

I want to perform scp with tunnel in between to some remote PC. I am using LIBSSH which has scp functionality but I am not able to figure out how to add a tunnel for scp. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What kind of tunnel? Why? Please elaborate on the matter.

Comment: here is the scenario  (My PC-->Linux PC--->Remote PC). So lets consider Linux PC is gateway for accessing Remote PC.So whenever i access Remote PC I need to go through Linux PC .Hence a tunnel is created between My Pc and Remote PC .I am using LIBSSH which has its own scp subsystem but i am not able to figure out how to copy files from my pc to remote PC using Linux Machine.This is same as when u use WINSCP and use scp protocol and in advanced options add a tunnel.Is it clear now???